# Transpose an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am attempting to transpose an array of objects in JavaScript.

I have this array of objects:

```js
var myData = [ 
{"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"255","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
{"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"445","moto":"273"},
{"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"412"},
{"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"432","moto":"378"},
{"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"420","moto":"319"},
{"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"310","moto":"413"},
{"shift":"7","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"155","truck":"177","bike":"377","moto":"180"},
{"shift":"8","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"179","truck":"203","bike":"405","moto":"222"},
{"shift":"9","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"208","truck":"185","bike":"360","moto":"195"},
{"shift":"10","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"150","truck":"290","bike":"315","moto":"280"},
{"shift":"11","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"220","bike":"350","moto":"205"},
{"shift":"12","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"170","bike":"390","moto":"400"}
];
out = '';
$.each(myData, function(ndx,obj){
  out += '{';
  $.each(obj, function(key,val){
     out += key +':'+ val +',';
   });
   out += '}<br>';
});
$('body').append(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need it to be transposed, so that (when transposed) it looks like this (note: I did this manually, I need to do it programmatically - and print it as above):

```
var myData2 = [
{"shift":"1","shift":"2","shift":"3","shift":"4","shift":"5","shift":"6","shift":"7","shift":"8","shift":"9","shift":"10","shift":"11","shift":"12"},
{"date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00"},
{"car":"178","car":"125","car":"140","car":"222","car":"200","car":"230","car":"155","car":"179","car":"208","car":"150","car":"200","car":"230"},
{"truck":"255","truck":"189","truck":"219","truck":"290","truck":"250","truck":"220","truck":"177","truck":"203","truck":"185","truck":"290","truck":"220","truck":"170"},
{"bike":"317","bike":"445","bike":"328","bike":"432","bike":"420","bike":"310","bike":"377","bike":"405","bike":"360","bike":"315","bike":"350","bike":"390"},
{"moto":"237","moto":"273","moto":"412","moto":"378","moto":"319","moto":"413","moto":"180","moto":"222","moto":"195","moto":"280","moto":"205","moto":"400"}
];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9vyv2nu/)

Comment: objects cannot have duplicate property names.

Comment: Thanks gang, I should have seen the fundamental problem with where I was going. This was for a d3.js application where the input data csv file has columnar data, so it is impossible to represent correctly. I was attempting to transpose the data to a row-oriented format, but clearly I've been working at this too long. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: If you need it for `d3` @trincot's answer and mine will both work. `@trincot`'s more elegant, but takes the keys from first element in your current data and assumes they all have the same structure. It will error if they're not. Mine won't, but that doesn't help you much, as d3 won't draw the expected chart (if any object is different). So you should go with `trincot`s answer. If you want to track objects with variable structure you must have a separate array of all properties and use `shift` as index/tracker.

Comment: Eh, @AndreiGheorghiu, my solution will not error if there are fewer or more properties in other rows, it will just skip properties that are not in the first object, and fill gaps with `undefined` when properties are missing in the other objects.

Comment: @trincot I'm afraid it will error if any object has a property the first one doesn't. However, that's hardly likely to happen in this case. Considering it comes from a database, I think your answer is solid and should be the accepted one.

Comment: That's what I wrote, it will skip it. But the way I do it, it guarantees that the 4th elements of all the arrays relate to the same original object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @trincot. Perhaps you should warn it doesn't work [`in IE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility), though?

Comment: I added an extended variant of my solution that will grab all properties wherever they occur, and fill gaps with `undefined` wherever they are missing.

Comment: I thank you for it. Not sure about OP, but I can assure you it's useful to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your desired result has duplicate properties, which is not allowed.

Instead, you could turn that inner structure into an array with just the values, and assign that to the property. Like this:

```
{
  "shift": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
  "date": ["01/01/2016/08/00/00", "01/01/2016/17/00/00", // ...etc
}
```

You can use this ES6 code for that transformation:

```
const result = Object.assign(...Object.keys(myData[0]).map( key =>
    ({ [key]: myData.map( o => o[key] ) })
));
```

```js
var myData = [ 
{"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"255","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
{"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"445","moto":"273"},
{"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"412"},
{"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"432","moto":"378"},
{"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"420","moto":"319"},
{"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"310","moto":"413"},
{"shift":"7","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"155","truck":"177","bike":"377","moto":"180"},
{"shift":"8","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"179","truck":"203","bike":"405","moto":"222"},
{"shift":"9","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"208","truck":"185","bike":"360","moto":"195"},
{"shift":"10","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"150","truck":"290","bike":"315","moto":"280"},
{"shift":"11","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"220","bike":"350","moto":"205"},
{"shift":"12","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"170","bike":"390","moto":"400"}
];

const result = Object.assign(...Object.keys(myData[0]).map( key =>
    ({ [key]: myData.map( o => o[key] ) })
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In case you cannot guarantee that all the objects have the same properties, but you want all occurring properties to be represented in the output, then you could first gather all properties that occur and keep the unique keys (with a `Set`):

```
const result = Object.assign(...Array.from(
    new Set(myData.reduce((keys, o) => keys.concat(Object.keys(o)), [] )),
    key => ({ [key]: myData.map( o => o[key] ) })
));
```

```js
var myData = [ 
{"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"255","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
{"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"445","moto":"273"},
{"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"412"},
{"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"432","moto":"378"},
{"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"420","moto":"319"},
{"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"310","moto":"413"},
{"shift":"7","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"155","truck":"177","bike":"377","moto":"180"},
{"shift":"8","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"179","truck":"203","bike":"405","moto":"222"},
{"shift":"9","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"208","truck":"185","bike":"360","moto":"195"},
{"shift":"10","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"150","truck":"290","bike":"315","moto":"280"},
{"shift":"11","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"220","bike":"350","moto":"205"},
{"shift":"12","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"170","bike":"390","moto":"400"}
];

const result = Object.assign(...Array.from(
    new Set(myData.reduce((keys, o) => keys.concat(Object.keys(o)), [] )),
    key => ({ [key]: myData.map( o => o[key] ) })
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is it the OP desired solution?

Comment: The problem is that the desired OP solution is not possible.

Comment: Exactly. I just wonder if OP is aware of it, if so - maybe it would be better to wait him precise his question (:

Comment: We are all different.;-) (BTW, are you a French speaker?)

Comment: Great answer! I'd only add a note informing about the limited support in [`IE and mobile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Since objects cannot have repeated properties, I recommend accumulating values with the same property name as arrays:

```js
function transpose(data) {
  let result = {};
  for (let row of data) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
      result[key] = result[key] || [];
      result[key].push(value); 
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Example:
let data = [ 
  {"shift": 1, "date": "01/01/2016/08/00/00"},
  {"shift": 2, "date": "01/01/2016/17/00/00"},
  {"shift": 3, "date": "02/01/2016/08/00/00"}
];

console.log(transpose(data)); // {"shift": [1, 2, 3], "date": [...]}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a safe typescript-friendly equivalent to trincot's oneliner using the new `Object.fromEntries` function:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(myData[0]).map(key => [key, myData.map(o => o[key])]))
```

Breaking this down a bit:

```
const keys = Object.keys(myData[0]);
const entries = keys.map(key => [key, myData.map(o => o[key])]);
const result = Object.fromEntries(entries)
```

The original code using Object.assign and the spread operator will throw an error if there are no keys, and so the TS compiler rejects the code with the error "Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.". The new code will result in `{}` if there are no keys.