# How can I invert array and object to a different outcome in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

For a project of my own I need something I've never done before. I have data from a database like this:

```
{
  domain1.com: [
    { city: "New-York" },
    { city: "Denver" },
    { city: "Las-Vegas" },
    { city: "Boston" },
  ]
},
{
  domain2.com: [
    { city: "Miami" },
    { city: "Las-Vegas" },
    { city: "Boston" },
  ]
},
{
  domain3.com: [
    { city: "New-York" },
    { city: "Miami" },
    { city: "Las-Vegas" },
    { city: "Chicago" },
  ]
}
```

So an object with a domain name and in it an array with city names

Is it possible to turn this around, so get a list with city and the associated domain names? For example, like this:

```
{
  New-York: [
    { domain: "domain1.com" },
    { domain: "domain3.com" },
  ]
},
{
  Denver: [
    { domain: "domain1.com" },
  ]
},
{
  Las-Vegas: [
    { domain: "domain1.com" },
    { domain: "domain2.com" },
    { domain: "domain3.com" },
  ]
},
{
  Boston: [
    { domain: "domain1.com" },
    { domain: "domain2.com" },
  ]
},
{
  Miami: [
    { domain: "domain2.com" },
    { domain: "domain3.com" },
  ]
},
{
  Chicago: [
    { domain: "domain3.com" },
  ]
},
```

Comment: Umm is it an object or an array...? Double check your code snippets real quick...

Comment: It's a bad idea to have an array of objects where each object has a different property. You should just use a single object where those are each properties.

Comment: E.g. `[{prop1: value1}, {prop2: value2}]` is better done as `{prop1: value1, prop2: value2}]`

Comment: Or `[{domain: domain1.com, cities: [...]}, {domain: domain2.com, cities: []}, ...]`

Comment: It is an object currently with an array inside with data. The output may also contain only array.

Comment: The act is generally termed "transposition", and there are many questions about how to do it. It would be good if you could post what you've tried, rather than just saying "I've tried a bunch of things".

Comment: @Barmar [{domain: domain1.com, cities: [...]}, {domain: domain2.com, cities: []}, ...] That would be ideal

Comment: Your first snippet is not an object. You have a bunch of comma-separated objects, so it looks like they're part of an array.

Comment: just think about it as a single object. then once you have solved it for that its just a question of creating a for loop where u repeat the exact same solution. also, you need to learn the basics of javascript first. creating hello world and all those basics, before you jump into an assignment like this.

Comment: To create your result, create an object whose properties are city names. Loop over the original array, adding city properties as needed.

Comment: See also [Transpose an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42880867/215552)

Comment: I'll work on it, thanks for the tips so far.

Comment: If it's from a database, can't you adjust the serverside script to deliver it to javascript the desired way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other comments may help with explaining.
I came up with this quick solution

```
const data = [
  {
    "domain1.com": [
      { city: "New-York" },
      { city: "Denver" },
      { city: "Las-Vegas" },
      { city: "Boston" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "domain2.com": [
      { city: "Miami" },
      { city: "Las-Vegas" },
      { city: "Boston" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "domain3.com": [
      { city: "New-York" },
      { city: "Miami" },
      { city: "Las-Vegas" },
      { city: "Chicago" }
    ]
  }
];

const cities = {};

data.forEach((domainObject) => {
  const domain = Object.keys(domainObject)[0];
  const currentCities = domainObject[domain];
  currentCities.forEach((cityObject) => {
    const city = cityObject.city;
    if (Array.isArray(cities[city])) {
      cities[city].push(domain);
    } else {
      cities[city] = [domain];
    }
  });
});

const result = [];

Object.entries(cities).map(([key, value]) => {
  result.push({ [key]: value });
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please don't post code as a link.

Comment: I'm going to try it for sure. I'll be back for sure. Thank you very much!

Comment: I modified it so it's not a link @Michel

Comment: thank you very much for this code. With a little tweaks and optimization I succeeded!

Comment: GG! Sorry I didn't take the time to refactor to make the code cleaner. Thanks for accepting the answer!